# Finding whether a XML doc is valid using Stacks in Java

Tags: java, xml, data-structures, stack

I need to find whether an XML doc is valid using stack. Can anyone help me figure out the required algorithm for this. This has been confusing me for quite sometime now.
Below is the example outputs for the program

[image: These are some example outputs for the program]

Comment: Just a guess from looking at what you wrote. If you push on to a stack on open tags and pop on close tags, the stack should be empty when you finish. Just a guess. I haven't tried it so I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the provided example which you have pasted above. You can easily solve it using a stack.

Firstly you would need a method that will take one input as tag and will return two pairs - whether it's opening or closing tag and secondly the string name.

For example:- when I call the method - `parseTag(String tag)` , and let's suppose the example tag here is - `<note>` , so it will return - `Tuple("note", true)`. True because it's opening tag and in case of - `</note>` , the method will return - `Tuple("note", false)`.

Now, once we have this method ready, let's start looking into our algorithm.

```
1. Lets declare a stack in java using - Stack<String> st = new Stack<>();
2. Now, lets start to iterate over our xml, based on different tags.
3. Call method parseTag(tag) on our tags while looping over xml and if its an opening tag, then push it on top of stack.
4. Else if its a closing tag, then check whether the top of the stack has same tag name as the current closing tag, if they dont match, then return false and break out of loop.
5. If we reach the end of while loop, check whether the stack is empty or not, because if a stack is valid, then its supposed to be empty. If not then return false.
6. At the end, if you reach this step, then return true as we are sure our provided xml is perfectly valid.
```

Hope this helps!